# advanced search using HayStack + Solr in Django?

Tags: python, django, search, solr, django-haystack

I tried the basic tutorial given at Haystack website http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html and its working fine for basic search.
But its search is not effective as suppose my `Note` module has 3 entries for `text` field.

1. Twitter Bootstrap designer need for designing/editing a website theme
2. Django (python) app using mod_wsgi, virtualenv, on Ubuntu
3. Python exam to be held in Rajasthan.

When i search for

`python` it results: **2 & 3** text field.

`python exam` it results: **3rd** text field

but when searched `python flask` it results in nothing. I want **2nd and 3rd** result again, as there is `python` keyword.

when searched `boot` no result, but it should show **1st** result, it has `boot` in **bootstrap** word.

when searched `pyton` again no result, but it should show **2nd and 3rd** result, since it only 1 char `h` missing from **python**.

when searched `bootstrap django` again no result, but it should show **1st and 2nd** result.

So, its looks like i'm missing some advanced settings of haystack.

How can i make it more effective search so that it given better results instead of just simply direct matching?

Answer (score 5):

I've replied to your various questions as inline responses.

> but when searched python flask it results in nothing. I want 2nd and
>   3rd result again, as there is python keyword.

You want to change the haystack operator from `AND` to `OR`. See http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.0/settings.html#haystack-default-operator for more information.

> when searched boot no result, but it should show 1st result, it has
>   boot in bootstrap word.

Look at `NgramField` and `EdgeNgramField` for partial matching.

> when searched pyton again no result, but it should show 2nd and 3rd
>   result, since it only 1 char h missing from python.

Look at haystack's spelling suggestions: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#spelling-suggestion

> when searched bootstrap django again no result, but it should show 1st
>   and 2nd result.

This is configured by the haystack operator.

---

An example configuration for Haystack 2.0+ with default operator set to `OR` and `INCLUDE_SPELLING=True`

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://localhost:9001/solr/default',
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    },
}
HAYSTACK_DEFAULT_OPERATOR = 'OR'
```

Comment: Where do i put 'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True, or HAYSTACK_DEFAULT_OPERATOR = 'OR'. I tried placing them in settings.py above HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS field and also inside HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS block also. But no effect.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example. The documentation also has a few examples worth looking at: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html

Comment: I have tried the same code as your already but 'OR' operator does not take effect. Is there any other setting change or modification needed in any other part of app?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with using the Solr backend, but have you tried calling `rebuild_index` and see if that helps?

Comment: yeah already tried rebuild_index and update_index both but still no luck.

Comment: OR operator and Ngram worked fine. Only part left is Spelling Check. I have updated all the config settins as per standard docs but don't know how to show the "suggestions" in the search template.

Comment: Spell Check is actually quite complicated, but the docs does provide a pretty good example here: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html#spelling-suggestions